# Django: How to create a listview and query based on urlpatterns in urls.py

Tags: python, django, listview, url, search

I have a question, if

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index',views.index, name='index'),
    path('resume',views.resume, name='resume'),
]
```

I would like create a listview with urlpatterns, like that:

```
<h2>Urls</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for object_list  in urlpatternsList %} #<<--Fix
            <li><a href={{ urlpatterns.name.url }} or {% url 'url:urlpatterns' name }}> #How tag to urlpatterns url ??
           {{ urlpatterns.name }}</a> </li> 
       {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

and a query maybe that:

**views.py**

```
from myproject.urls import urlpatterns #<<-- problem when import

   def UrlPatternsQuery(request):
       query = request.GET.get(search,none)           

       if query:
           urlpatternsList = urlpatterns.objects.all()
           urlpatternsList = urlpatternsList.filter(name=query) # ex: name='resume'

       else:
           urlpatternsList = urlpatterns.objects.all()

   return render(request,'query.html', {'urlpatternsList':urlpatternsList})
```

Search Example

```
<div class="search-container">
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit">Search/button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Can you help ? Tks

[EDIT]: Show this problem in shell "AttributeError: module 'myapp.views' has no attribute 'index'"

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What is not working?

Comment: You are sending "urlpatternsList" in template but using "object_list". I have edited my answer. It will create link for each url mentioned in urls.py.

Comment: Sorry to answer late, the error is that   "AttributeError: module 'myapp.views' has no attribute 'index' "

Comment: @DanielRoseman I  don't know how attribute in "<a href=????????>"

Comment: Why not `{% url name %}`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman some problem

Comment: Well that problem doesn't have anything to do with the code you have posted. If you want to reference `views.index`, you need to define an `index` method in views.py.

Comment: My problem is "from myapp.urls import urlpatterns" , when I use comment (#) , django works , but I can't create list.

Answer (score 0):

**urlpatterns is a list.**

Pass urlpatterns to template

views.py

```
    context = {    

            'urlpatterns': urlpatterns
        }
     return render(request,'query.html', context)
```

In template

```
<h2>Urls</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for url_name in urlpatterns %}
            <li><a href="{% url url_name.name %}"> {{ urlpatterns.name }}</a> </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: I try this , but show this error : "AttributeError: module 'myapp.views' has no attribute 'index' "